# Cloudfront mp4 cache issue

Tags: amazon-s3, caching, amazon-cloudfront, mp4

I try to create video distribution system with `Cloudfront` and `S3`.
I created environment like this.
`Cloudfront` -> `S3`(origin)
I put `mp4` files and tried to access them, but every time the response is :

> 'x-cache: Miss from cloudfront'.

My Cloudfront Behavior setting is like this.

```
Cache Based on Slected Request Headers : None
Default TTL 999999999
Forward Cookies : None
Query String Forwarding and Caching** : None
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you add the complete response headers here ?